# Is Morse code without spaces uniquely decipherable?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

Are all Morse code strings uniquely decipherable?  Without the spaces,

```
......-...-..---.-----.-..-..-..
```

could be `Hello World` but perhaps the first letter is a `5` -- in fact it looks very unlikely an arbitrary sequence of dots and dashes should have a unique translation.

[image]

One might possibly use the [Kraft inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%27s_inequality) but that only applies to *prefix codes*.

Morse code *with spaces* is [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) in which messages can always be uniquely decoded.  Once we remove the spaces this is no longer true.

---

In the case I am right, and all Morse code message can't be uniquely decoded, is there a way to list all the possible messages?  Here are some related exercise I found on codegolf.SE

- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36735/morse-decode-golf
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131/morse-code-translator

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question already?

Comment: "Morse code without spaces" is not morse code. The spaces are part of the specification because without them the code is not decipherable.

Comment: @StephenKennedy That's already in the question. Did you read it completely?

Comment: [Perl script](http://pastebin.com/kALJDykj) to list possible messages for a code. Didn't realize this was a purely theoretical community. :)

Comment: Without the presence of control bits, such data could become misinterpreted. They chose "space" for this purpose, but it could just have easily been -- or .., assuming the codes were designed such that no symbol could produce those codes accidentally.

Comment: I wrote a program once as part of a contest that read in "morse code without spaces" and used a dictionary to "guess" the message.  Turns out there's a LOT of potential matches, and the longer the code, the number of matches gets exponentially larger.

Comment: The most trivial example: ".." is either "ee" or "i".  If you know the string's length then "-.-" is either "nt" or "ta" (as well as "k").

Comment: Spin-off question: [Find the longest morsagram word pair](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6083/).

Comment: Are you really sure your accepted answer qualifies as an answer at all, or even as a hint to anything? I mean it is obvious  that ET=A ... which proves that Spielberg was right: ET is an Alien.

Comment: Even the famous SOS is not uniquely decipherable without inter-letter spaces/pauses, as SOS could also mean 3B.

Comment: There are 3 kinds of spaces in Morse code. Which do you have in mind?

Comment: Generally Morse code is not a prefix free code. But a prefix free code has the properties of being uniquely decodable without delimiters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The following are both plausible messages, but have a completely different meaning:

```
SOS HELP      = ...---...  .... . .-.. .--.        => ...---.........-...--.
I AM HIS DATE = ..  .- --  .... .. ...  -.. .- - . => ...---.........-...--.
```

Comment: Cute but it's already been established that Morse without spaces is ambiguous so I don't really think this is worth much more than a comment.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking whether one series of dots and dashes without spaces could be interpreted as two "real" messages as opposed to arbitrary sequences of _T_ and _E_. The first _SOS! Help!_ is composed of two interjections and the second _I am his date_ is a grammatical and sensible English sentence so both are valid messages. This answers the question succinctly by providing an example.

Comment: @CJDennis The question doesn't say that at all. It asks if there Morse strings are uniquely decipherable and if there's a way of listing all the strings that code to a given sequence if dots and dashes. It says nothing at all about the strings having to have meaning in English.

Comment: there is both a _specific_ (counter)example and a _general_ way to study the problem and _both_ are relevant to good answer(s). see eg [proofs/refutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_and_Refutations) by lakatos

Comment: @CJDennis The OP does NOT seem to be asking for real messages. Anyway, real messages in morse may well be encoded so as to be non distinguishable from garbage.

Comment: "What does it say, ensign?" `I AM HIS DATE` "So [Amelia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelia_Earhart) decided to elope with old [Noonan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Noonan), hmmm. We should probably keep this to ourselves."

Answer (score 39):

Quoting David Richerby from the comments:

> Since ⋅ represents E and − represents T, any Morse message without spaces can be interpreted as a string in $\{E,T\}^*$

Further, since A, I, M, and N are represented by the four possible combinations of two morse characters (⋅-, ⋅⋅, --, -⋅, respectively), any message without spaces can also be interpreted as a string in  $\{A,I,M,N\}^*\{E,T\}?$.  Note that for any Morse message of length > 1, this is distinct from David's interpretation.  Thus, the only messages with unique interpretations are those of length 1 (and, I suppose, 0, if that counts as a message) - that is, ⋅, representing E, and -, representing T.

Here's some JavaScript that will tell you all possible interpretations of a string of `.` and `-`.  Strings of up to length 22 run in under a second, but anything higher than that starts getting pretty slow - I wouldn't, for example, try to decode HELLO WORLD with it.  You can pop open a JavaScript console in your browser, paste this in, and then call, for example, `decode('......-...-..---')`.  (In this example, entry #2446 is the intended string "HELLO".)

```
var decode = function(code) {
  var cache = {
    '0': ['']
  };
  for(var start = 0;start < code.length;start++) {
    for(var len = 1;len < 6;len++) {
      if(start + len > code.length) continue;
      if(!cache[start + len]) cache[start + len] = [];
      var curCode = code.slice(start, start + len);
      if(dict[curCode]) {
        for(var i_start = 0;i_start < cache[start].length;i_start++) {
          cache[start + len].push(cache[start][i_start] + dict[curCode]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return cache[code.length];
};

var dict = {
  '.-': 'A',
  '-...': 'B',
  '-.-.': 'C',
  '-..': 'D',
  '.': 'E',
  '..-.': 'F',
  '--.': 'G',
  '....': 'H',
  '..': 'I',
  '.---': 'J',
  '-.-': 'K',
  '.-..': 'L',
  '--': 'M',
  '-.': 'N',
  '---': 'O',
  '.--.': 'P',
  '--.-': 'Q',
  '.-.': 'R',
  '...': 'S',
  '-': 'T',
  '..-': 'U',
  '...-': 'V',
  '.--': 'W',
  '-..-': 'X',
  '-.--': 'Y',
  '--..': 'Z',
  '.----': '1',
  '..---': '2',
  '...--': '3',
  '....-': '4',
  '.....': '5',
  '-....': '6',
  '--...': '7',
  '---..': '8',
  '----.': '9',
  '-----': '0'
};
```

The code to prune it to only strings of real words is a bit longer, so I put it [here](http://pastebin.com/ExnEife1).  It runs under node.js and expects a file at `/usr/share/dict/words-2500`.  The dictionary I'm using can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/mYrkjdhY).  It is not naive - it prunes as it goes, so it runs *much* faster on larger inputs.

The dictionary consists of a top-2500 words list I found on the internet somewhere, minus some 1-, 2-, and 3- letter combinations that I deemed not words.  This algorithm is sensitive to having too many short words to choose from, and slows down drastically if you allow, say, every individual letter as a word (I'm looking at you, `/usr/share/dict/words`).

The algorithm finishes by sorting based on the number of words, so the "interesting" ones will hopefully be at the top.  This works great on `HELLO WORLD`, running in under a second and returning the expected phrase as the first hit.  From this I also learned that `DATA SCIENTIST` (the only other phrase I tried) morse codes the same as `NEW REAL INDIA`.

Edit:  I searched for more interesting ones for a few minutes.  The words `SPACES` and `SWITCH` are morsagrams.  So far they're the longest single-word pair I've found.

Comment: Have you just invented the word **morsagram** ? I like it very much, but a web-search provided a *single* link - to this site.

Comment: I have also taken the liberty to turn this interesting question into an [open challenge on Puzzling.SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6083/open-ended-challenge-find-the-longest-morsagram-word-pair) with some reference back to this posting here.

Comment: @BmyGuest Yeah, that's a completely made-up word.  I kinda like it, though.

Answer (score 17):

It is enough to observe that certain short combinations of letters give ambiguous decodings. A single ambiguous sequence suffices, but I can see the following:

```
ATE ~ P
EA ~ IT
MO ~ OM
```

*etc.* As David Richerby notes in the comments, any letter is equivalent to a string of Es and Ts, which makes Morse Code ambiguous as a way of encoding arbitrary sequences of letters; the above combinations show that this is true even of plausible letter combinations in English (for instance, `MEAT` ~ `MITT`). Perhaps an interesting coding exercise would be to find all strings of five or fewer letters which could be mistaken for something else, restricting to letter combinations that may actually be found in English text (using one or more words), grouped by equivalence class.

Using your original example, it also happens to be the case that

```
HELLO WORLD ~ HAS TEAM NO MAID TOE
```

and while the right-hand side is perhaps unrealistic even as a partial message, it is certainly a sequence of English words, and one that could be found in less than 15 minutes without computer assistance. This could be taken as evidence that many phrases in English could be misparsed as a different (possibly nonsensical) sequence of English words.

Comment: MT vs TM is a very short example.

Comment: @Raphael MT == TM == O All three are the same sequence. That makes it very difficult to translate.

Answer (score 11):

Morse Code is actually a ternary code, not a binary code, so the spaces are necessary. If spaces were not there, a lot of ambiguity would result, not so much with the entire message, but with individual letters.

For example, 2 dots is an I, but 3 dots is an S. If you are transcribing and you hear two dots, do you immediately write "I" or do you wait until you hear another dot (or dash)?

The answer is that each value is space separated so they are grouped together. When operators key messages in Morse, they make a pause of the same length as a dash after each letter code sequence to indicate the end of the sequence.

Even if you wrote an AI program to look at a full sentence at a time and figure out what was the logical interpretation of the message, there would still be many slight ambiguities and misspellings that would

Comment: Your last sentence seems to have been truncated.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, that is because I tried to make post using Morse Code with no spaces.

Answer (score 5):

a few notes not covered in other (good) answers but which dont generally research prior knowledge and *cite* any stuff (to me an intrinsic part of computer *science*).

- this general theory of CS falls into the category of [text segmentation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segmentation) and also "word splitting"/ "disambiguation" although there the theory is a bit different, its about splitting sequences of symbols into words (with variable letters), etc, where the symbols are units. here the strings are split into letters where letters have variable length, but the theory is analogous although not exactly 1-1. ie mapping between sentences-into-words, variable-word-letter-lengths, and sentences-into-words, variable-word/letter-lengths.
- as others have pointed out this can be studied empirically. and someone did that from one angle (there are multiple ways to study this) and "published" the results on a [web page](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/march42012/results.html) with a big directory/ table of results.

  > I found 25,787 ambiguous Morse code words. This is made of 10,330 distinct Morse strings. The highest frequency ambiguous Morse word has 13 possible donor words. The results are grouped below in tables based on the frequency of words that share the same Morse representation.
- wow, "context matters"... a nearly identical question ["translating morse code without spaces"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349136/translating-morse-code-with-no-spaces) on stackoverflow from 3yrs ago currently has 0 votes.

Answer (score 2):

In general there are exponentially many possible decodings, but if you really want you can list them all. You can also list them in a succinct way, that is, give a succinct representation for all of them. Since this is nothing more than a programming exercise, I challenge you to do it yourself.

That said, the fact that there is ambiguity does not preclude the ability to decipher the message, or at least large parts of the message. Assuming a probabilistic model for the text represented by the Morse code – for definiteness, we can assume that it's English and use statistical properties of English – it may be possible to essentially decode the message, though some local ambiguities may be unavoidable. The reason is that most decodings correspond to non-sense plaintext. The way to do it is to extend the dynamic programming algorithm from the previous paragraph to estimate the likelihood of each decoding, and then choose the maximum likelihood decoding. This approach has more chance to succeed as the message gets longer.

Comment: Doesn't the [Viterbi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) do something similar to what you described?  Quantifying the exponential growth of the number of decodings, is that an appropriate question for here, or cstheory.SE?

Comment: That's right, the idea is to use dynamic programming. Estimating the exponential growth probably fits here better than cstheory.

Comment: actually, this is very similar to what is done to identify words in speech processing. The result is what is called a word lattice, that is a condensed representation of all the word sequences that could match the sound sequence analyzed.

Answer (score 1):

### How to define/recognize/generate the language of all possible decodings.

Clearly, without spaces, the morse code is no longer uniquely
decipherable.

It is however possible to give in a condensed form all the possible
ways to decode it. This is actually similar to what is done in speech
processing: from a unique stream of sounds (or of phonems), you have
to find all the ways it can be decomposed in a sequence of words.
The algorithms for doing this produce what is called a word lattice.
You will find an example in the "lexical ambiguity" section of [this
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903007/algorithms-or-data-structures-for-dealing-with-ambiguity/26132215#26132215).

In the case of binary Morse code (no spaces), you have only dots and
dashes, but the problem is the same.

The way you can get all translations is as follow.

First you build [Generalized Sequential Machine (GSM)](http://planetmath.org/generalizedsequentialmachine) $T$ that decodes the
a Morse sentence. This is easily achieved by building a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) that
recognizes Morse code. When a code is recognized, the corresponding
letter/digit is output, and there is (non deterministically) an empty
transition back to the root of the trie. But at the same time, the
code word may be continued into a longer one (non-deterministically).

Then you take your Morse sequence $w$ of $n$ dashes and dots, and you read it
as a linear finite state automaton $W$ with $n+1$ states (the positions
between the dashes and dots, from $0$ to $n$) that generates this
unique sentence, i.e. the singleton language $L=\{w\}=\mathcal L(W)$. What you want is
the language of all translations $T(L)$. You know from general theorems
that, since L is finite, hence regular, and since regular languages
are closed under GSM mappings, that the language $T(L)$ is regular. So
what you really want is a FSA that recognizes (or generates) that language.

For that purpose, you can simply apply a standard cross-product
construction, similar to the one used for the intersection of two
regular languages, to the two finites states devices $T$ and $W$.  The
transition are chosen so that you mimic both the transducer $T$ and
the FSA $W$. **You easily get a FSA that defines the regular language of all
translations.**

The details are easily worked out. But ask if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo-code for a solver that will give all possible interpretations. This is based on a few quick thoughts, so additional input would be welcome. Method accepts two inputs one of the text so far translated, and the second of morse code.

```
MorseSolver (string textSoFar, string codeRemaining)
{
    if(codeRemaining length == 0) output textSoFar
    else
    {
        codeLength = length of code remaining
        read 1 through (min of 5 or codeLength) characters from codeRemaining
        for each set of characters
        {
            call an IsMorseCode method that checks if the characters 
              input are valid morse code
            if they are valid add the translated character to textSoFar 
              and remove the characters from codeRemaining, then call 
              the MorseSolver again with the new strings)
        }

}
```

This will output all the possible combinations of letters and numbers without any spaces between "words". If you wanted to prove the ambiguity, this would certainly do it. If you wanted to get some meaningful messages out, then try looking for code meant to translate hashtags into readable language.

Using the above, I wrote a program in C# which does the above. I stopped it from running at 22 million possibilities for the above string that can translate to hello world. The Morse Code equivalent of "Hello" resulted in 20,569 possible results. I also did not include the numbers. That would be higher if I allowed them.

Comment: The output of such an algorithm would be a proof that any individual string is ambiguous but it wouldn't prove that *all* strings are ambiguous.

Comment: @DavidRicherby All strings of length > 1 are ambiguous. That has been proven elsewhere on this page. I was attempting to answer the second part of the question, and provide a means to extrapolate all possible solutions from a string.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would you share your C# program? [My Perl version](http://pastebin.com/kALJDykj) comes up with 19796 possible solutions for the "HELLO" equivalent. Most probably I forgot to output some cases though...

Comment: Real source code is offtopic here; please publish it elsewhere (pastebin, Gist, ...) and only link to it.